# Defining components from @mui/material and @mui/labs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to use components from the external libraries @mui/material and @mui/labs without success. The following is my code:

```
import { Box, Tab } from '@mui/material'
import { TabContext, TabList, TabPanel } from '@mui/lab'
import React, { useState } from 'react'


export const MuiTabs = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('1')
    
    const handleChanged: Function = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: string) => {
        setValue(newValue)
    }
    return <Box>
        <TabContext value={value}>
            <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider'}}>
                <TabList aria-label='Example Tabs' onChange={handleChanged} textColor='secondary' indicatorColor='secondary' centered>
                    <Tab label='Tab One' value='1' />
                    <Tab label='Tab Two' value='2' />
                    <Tab label='Tab Three' value='3' />
                </TabList>
            </Box>
            
            <TabPanel value='1'>
                Panel one
            </TabPanel>

            <TabPanel value='2'>
                Panel two
            </TabPanel>

            <TabPanel value='3'>
                Panel three
            </TabPanel>

        </TabContext>
    </Box>
}
```

As I define components from these libraries I'm getting the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & BoxOwnProps<Theme> & Omit<any, keyof BoxOwnProps<Theme>>): Element | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<BoxTypeMap<{}, "div", Theme>>): Element | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2769)
Box.d.ts(186, 3): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: ElementType<any>; } & BoxOwnProps<Theme> & Omit<any, keyof BoxOwnProps<Theme>>'
Box.d.ts(186, 3): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BoxOwnProps<Theme> & Omit<Omit<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "ref"> & { ...; }, keyof BoxOwnProps<...>>'
```

Any idea what could be the issue here?

I have searched online for this problem and couldn't find anything related to my issue here. I have also tried to use various versions of the mentioned libraries with no success. This is a very simple code snippet and should work, so my guess this has something to do with the installed related packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this (confirmed working):

Note: The function name matches yours `MuiTabs` ... the filename is unspecified in the question; in this example, it is`Demo.tsx` here ... ofc you can change it as needed:

```
//./Demo.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: number;
  value: number;
}

function CustomTabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: number) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

export default function MuiTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      <CustomTabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </CustomTabPanel>
      <CustomTabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </CustomTabPanel>
      <CustomTabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </CustomTabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

And the index.tsx

```
// ./index.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Demo from './Demo';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <Demo />
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This is from the official MUI docs [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/) and [here](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=Demo.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answers above and an extensive search online - all didn't help to solve my issue.

The only workaround (not a solution) to this problem for me was to use yarn instead of npm to install my node modules. I'm not entirely sure what was the cause for the issue, but again, seems logical that it is related to packages and or software versions.